# devise auth token current_user return nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, react-redux, rails-api, devise-token-auth

I want acsess to `current_user` in `devise aoth token gem` but its return nil or error :  `"You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."`

I use redux-token-auth package for client side , and client side do login and register user successfully

But in in server side  `Rails-api`  i can't get current_user data

Rails server in port : 3001
Clinet server in port : 3000

gems :

```
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'devise'
```

---

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
   protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

---

Devise Auth Token

```
DeviseTokenAuth.setup do |config|
  config.change_headers_on_each_request = false
  config.token_lifespan = 10.day
end
```

---

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do 
    namespace :v1 do 
     resources :wallets , only: [:index, :show]
    end 
  end 
end
```

---

Rack CROS :

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options, :delete, :put]
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://devise-token-auth.gitbook.io/devise-token-auth/usage/controller_methods), you can include the namespace in the authentication method:

```
before_action :authenticate_api_v1_user!
```

then the current user will be:

```
current_api_v1_user
```